# Knockout.js Dynamic HTML Binding returning [object Object]

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm just starting out with Knockout.js, and I've got a query about dynamic HTML.

I'm creating a dynamic Questionnaire. This has;

- The Main Questionnaire View Model, which contains ...
- An observableArray of Pages, which contains ...
- An observableArray of Questions, which contains ...
- An Array of Options.

I've mapped my options using the $.map function, like;

```
this.options = $.map(questionOptions, function(text) { 
                                                       return new Option(text) 
                                                     });
```

I'm generating some html dynamically in the ViewModel, however when I try and concatenate say the Option Text into something like a set of Radio Buttons;

```
var htmlContent = '';
ko.utils.arrayForEach(_self.options, function (item) {
    htmlContent += '<input type="radio" name="' + ko.utils.unwrapObservable(_self.questionNumber) + '" data-bind="attr: {value: value}, checked: $root.selected" />\r\n';
    htmlContent += '<span>\r\n';
    htmlContent += item.optionText;
    //htmlContent += ko.utils.unwrapObservable(item.optionText); // Doesn't Work
    //htmlContent += item.optionText(); // Doesn't Work
    htmlContent += '</span>\r\n';
                });

return htmlContent;
```

I end up with a bunch of;

```
[object Object]
```

I've tried a couple of alternatives and gotten a bit stuck with where to go..

I'm not sure how to use Templates, as I'm planning on having Text Boxes, Radio Buttons, Drops Downs, Lists, etc all together. But maybe my knowledge is just lacking here!?

Here's a jsFiddle with some example code;

http://jsfiddle.net/PGallagher69/wA6mQ/21/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `optionText` is indeed an `Option` object.

Try:

```
htmlContent += item.optionText.optionText;
```

**UPDATE:**

The real problem lies here:

```
function PagesViewModel(pageNo, pageHeader, questions) {
    this.pageNumber = ko.observable(pageNo);
    this.pageHeaderText = ko.observable(pageHeader);

    this.questionItems = ko.observableArray($.map(questions, function (n) {
        return [new QuestionViewModel(n.questionType, n.questionNumber, n.questionText, n.pointsBudget, n.options)]
    }));
}
```

When you're creating your `PagesViewModel`, the `questions` parameter is already an array of `QuestionViewModel` objects, and by assigning `this.questionItems` with your custom function, you're re-creating the `QuestionViewModel`, passing it `n.options` that is already an array of `Option` objects thus re-wrapping it again with an `Option` object, and that is why you're eventually gonna need `item.optionText.optionText` instead of simply `item.optionText`.

Try this:

```
function PagesViewModel(pageNo, pageHeader, questions) {
    this.pageNumber = ko.observable(pageNo);
    this.pageHeaderText = ko.observable(pageHeader);
    this.questionItems = ko.observable(questions);
}
```

Comment: You're Right! How is that happenning, do you know?

Comment: Seems like your `_self.options` is containing double values, stil checking.

Comment: I can't see why it's happening... Very confusing!! :-(

Comment: Genius! Well spotted! Thanks a million! If only I could vote up twice! Teehee